# Is my spartan juniper sick?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, conifers

Earlier this year (early April), I had a half dead tree removed from my yard and we planted some spartan juniper trees along our fence to replace it. I noticed this past weekend that one of them is starting to look like it's a little stressed.

Here's what one of the healthy trees look like: [image: healthy tree]

And here are some pictures of the tree I'm worried about: [image: unhealthy tree][image: unhealthy tree][image: unhealthy tree]

I've been roughly following the watering guidelines in https://extension.umn.edu/planting-and-growing-guides/watering-newly-planted-trees-and-shrubs, giving them ~5 gallons of water every couple days, and recently moving down to weekly waterings. I live in the Boulder/Denver area where we've been having a pretty hot, dry summer.

Is this something to be worried about? My first thought was that maybe this tree needs more water, is that the right action to take, or is there something else going on?